# How to convert Hex to String in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, hex

Here is my hex input

```
0x3c0x3c0x5bIMG0x5d0x5bSIZE0x5dHALF0x5b0x2fSIZE0x5d0x5bID0x5d540x5b0x2fID0x5d0x5b0x2fIMG0x5d0x3e0x3e
```

Expected output is :

```
<<[IMG][SIZE]HALF[/SIZE][ID]54[/ID][/IMG]>>
```

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/132996/convert-hexadecimal-to-varchar

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),0x3c0x3c0x5bIMG0x5d0x5bSIZE0x5dHALF0x5b0x2fSIZE0x5d0x5bID0x5d540x5b0x2fID0x5d0x5b0x2fIMG0x5d0x3e0x3e);

Comment: This link doenst help me.  Need to get exact <<[IMG][SIZE]HALF[/SIZE][ID]54[/ID][/IMG]>> this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's for only a small set of ascii codes that always need replacement in a variable, then you can also replace them like this:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = '0x3c0x3c0x5bIMG0x5d0x5bSIZE0x5dHALF0x5b0x2fSIZE0x5d0x5bID0x5d540x5b0x2fID0x5d0x5b0x2fIMG0x5d0x3e0x3e';

select @string = replace(@string,hex,chr)
from (values 
('0x3c','<'),
('0x3e','>'),
('0x5b','['),
('0x5d',']'),
('0x2f','/')
) hexes(hex,chr);

select @string as string;
```

Returns:

```
string
------
<<[IMG][SIZE]HALF[/SIZE][ID]54[/ID][/IMG]>>
```

If there are more characters, or hardcoding is frowned upon?
Then looping a replacement will also get that result:

```
declare @string varchar(max) = '0x3c0x3c0x5bIMG0x5d0x5bSIZE0x5dHALF0x5b0x2fSIZE0x5d0x5bID0x5d540x5b0x2fID0x5d0x5b0x2fIMG0x5d0x3e0x3e';

declare @loopcount int = 0;
declare @hex char(4);
while (patindex('%0x[0-9][a-f0-9]%',@string)>0 
       and @loopcount < 128) -- just safety measure to avoid infinit loop
begin
    set @hex = substring(@string,patindex('%0x[0-9][a-f0-9]%',@string),4);
    set @string = replace(@string, @hex, convert(char(1),convert(binary(2), @hex, 1)));
    set @loopcount = @loopcount + 1;
end;

select @string as string;
```

If you would wrap it in a UDF then you can even use it in a query.

Comment: This is what I am looking for , Really appreciated your help !!

Comment: @NileshBankar Thanks. I've included a non-hardcoded version for if there's more codes to replace.

Answer (score 3):

Your string is mixing hex and char data, so you need to parse it with a code. A tricky part is converting `0xCC` substring to a char it represents. First pretend it's binary and then cast to char. Using recursion to iterate over all `0xCC` substrings

```
declare @imp nvarchar(max) = '0x3c0x3c0x5bIMG0x5d0x5bSIZE0x5dHALF0x5b0x2fSIZE0x5d0x5bID0x5d540x5b0x2fID0x5d0x5b0x2fIMG0x5d0x3e0x3e';

with cte as (
select replace(col, val, cast(convert(binary(2), val, 1) as char(1))) as col
 from (
   -- sample table
   select @imp as col
   ) tbl
 cross apply (select patindex('%0x__%',tbl.col) pos) p
 cross apply (select substring(col,pos,4) val) v
union all
select replace(col, val, cast(convert(binary(2), val, 1) as char(1))) as col
 from cte 
 cross apply (select patindex('%0x__%',col) pos) p
 cross apply (select substring(col,pos,4) val) v
where pos > 0
)
select * 
from cte
where patindex('%0x__%',col) = 0;
```

Returns

```
col
<<[IMG][SIZE]HALF[/SIZE][ID]54[/ID][/IMG]>>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!